# Dynamic query error "invalid character"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am tring to run a simple dynamic query but obtain:

```
DECLARE 
  stm varchar2(20000) ; 
BEGIN
  stm :=  'SELECT 12 X FROM DUAL ;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stm ;
END;
```

but obtain the error :

> ORA-00911: invalid character ORA-06512: at line 5
>   00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
>   *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>              letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>              character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>              any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>              (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>              delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>              Reference Manual.

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the first semicolon `;';` here

Comment: You also probably want the query result to go somewhere; if so you need another variable and an `into` clause, [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24260667/266304). And obviously this query doesn't need to be dynamic, but I assume you're experimenting *8-)

Comment: yes it is not actually dynamical query but just a sample; it I reduced the query so that to be minimal, but the stm string can be easily built to get the query dynamic. ta

Comment: yes , it was the semicolon in the smt string, now it works. ta

Comment: again yes, I see the answer to the "run query as strings in oracle" , I agree  my question is duplicate; not sure how to merge the questions or what to do next. I searched for this error for dynamic query and missed this answer. thanks a lot Paul

Comment: @user3752281 - you don't need to do anything, this question is [marked as a duplicate now](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and will stay here as a signpost - someone else might find your question more easily than the other one, and will be directed there for the answer. Glad it helped.